# Ant target to check out from Visual Source safe

Tags: java, ant, visual-sourcesafe

I need to write a ant target to checkout VSS project from a vss lable to the local machine.
lets say VSS username 'bob' and password '123' and the vss project name is ANT_TEST. Lable I want check out is V.1.0 to local folder E:\ANTTEST. Can some one pls guid me to do that.

Comment: I know this is somewhat OT, but it is highly recommended to not use VSS.

Comment: @paul I don't have anyother option. Reason is in my company they use VSS for version controlling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Microsoft Visual SourceSafe Tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/vss.html).

They are optional tasks, so you might have to add libraries to your ant installation if the task is not found.  In the event that they are not already installed, [details about optional tasks can be found here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html).

```
<vsscheckout vsspath="$/ANT_TEST"
         localpath="D:\ANTTEST"
         label="V.1.0"
         recursive="true"
         login="bob,123"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ant has [VSS tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/vss.html).  It sounds like the `vsscheckout` task would do what you need.  Perhaps:

```
<vsscheckout vsspath="$/ANT_TEST"
         localpath="E:\ANTTEST"
         recursive="true"
         label="V.1.0"
         login="bob,123"/>
```